# Remove audio snippet from many audio files

Tags: audio, music, sound-editing

I have a lot of audio files (.mp3) which all contain a specific audio snippet on different timestamps in those audiofiles. How could I remove those snippets automatically in all audio files?

Comment: I think by the time you've set up & trained an AI to do it for you, you could have done it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only manually and file by file - if at all. How easily depends largely on what exactly you want to remove.

If the snippet has a clear, audible period of silence at both ends, you can simply open the file in an audio editor such as Audacity, Ocenaudio etc., paying attention that you cut at zero crossings as to avoid audible clicks. Bring the ends of the truncated waveform together and save the new file.

If there's no clear silence, it gets difficult. This is because an audio waveform is a very complex thingy, just cutting at zero crossings is usually not enough. I've tried that myself often enough in the past; matching the audio without audible clicks and pops is well-nigh impossible.

If the "snippet" is an overlaid recorded watermark such as "produced by ACME" on top of a sample, there's no way without destroying the original audio.

There's really no use for this kind of tool even in professional audio production; unless *maybe* in movie post-processing which I'm not familiar with. Even if such automatable tool exists it's bound to be VERY expensive, considering that the professional toolsets for noise reduction etc. cost several thousands.

EDIT to clarify the "why".

Let's start with the fact that computers do not work with audio, they work with chunks of data. Bits and bytes, and only with bits and bytes. And computers are *very* stupid.

ASCII-coded word "hello" consists of characters 104, 101, 108, 108, 111. It's a clear-cut string of bytes, unchanging. Therefore it's a trivial task to remove or replace the single word in a multitude of text files. Words "Hello", "hEllo" or "HelLo" are no longer identical, so you will need to instruct the computer to handle those separately.

Record yourself saying "hello" three times, exactly the same way. A human being might not hear any difference, but you *will* have produced three unique waveforms, and computer will see three unique strings of bits and bytes.

Record "hello" on your phone, play it back three times recording it with a computer. *Any* difference in the situation - moving the phone a millmeter to any direction, one of the recordings being ever so slightly louder, 100th of a second difference in starting the playback - will again have produced three unique waveforms, i.e. unique strings of bits and bytes.

Again, you will need to instruct the computer to remove each unique string of bits and bytes separately.

The problem here is very similar to face recognition. As @Tetsujin already hinted, this requires an AI.

Removing absolute, perfect silence is another trivial task as it's always identical string of zero bytes. Removing background noise (almost-perfect silence) less so; you will have to teach the system what "noise" is in the first place; and choose appropriate parameters to remove *just* the noise and nothing else. And it's effective only as long as the noise is constant... if AC starts to blow higher, the background noise has changed and you will need to adjust your parameters.

Then there's the other practical side...

Tools are created to perform tasks. The more common the task, the more tools are available and the cheaper they get. An example would be equalization or compression - we do it all the time, so there's a huge number of tools ranging from free to moderately expensive. There's a need, people will buy; even if good free options are available.

Clip repair, scratch removal and other such tasks are still part of the job, but far less often performed than just everyday mixing. Consequently the market for those tools is much smaller, and the prices are higher. Professional toolsets for this purpose cost thousands, but because there's a need, people will buy.

Removing a single word or sentence from a large number of audio files is not by any stretch of imagination a common task. Even if we do remove and rearrange audio, it's always an one-time job per track, never on scale like you're talking about. Consequently, should someone create such a tool, the market would be minuscule which would make the cost prohibitive.

I can't honestly even envision any legal purpose for it; except for maybe removing F-bombs. But due to the price it'd still be more cost-effective, not to mention reliable and accurate, to just let the soundguys do it manually.

I hope this clarifies it. There are no "magic" apps - there are tools to fill needs, in market-driven proportion to said needs. No need, no market, no tool.

Comment: You just gave me a hilarious mental image… of every couple of minutes during a take, the boom-op yelling "This is a recording for Notflux, all rights reserved" & leaving it to post to figure out how to edit round it ;))

Comment: LOL :-D I've bumped into some commercial loops where you actually do have a "produced by" or "downloaded from" overlay :-)

Comment: Sure - though presumably you can buy your way out of that. As a non-sequitur… why are all studios next to airports? "Ok… and… turnover please.. ah… hold for the plane…holding the roll" ;)

Comment: Of course, it's just a way of providing a preview for potential customers. A proper studio is an expensive building project, and available space near airports tends to be for some reason comparatively cheap... :-D

Comment: Most of the studios around here either pre-date the airports, or were built on them;) Pinewood, Elstree [older than the airports nearby], Leavesden [used to *be* an airport & the only one in West London to have avoided newer ones;) The ones under construction all seem to be North or East

Comment: @Tetsujin "Guys, I found an ideal place - a bit away from the center so pretty cheap, but the surroundings be nice and quiet!" :-D

Comment: LOL, yup. Pinewood was built 10 years before Heathrow… go figure ;))

Comment: Ok, but the snippet I'm talking about is neither silence or an overlay. It is just a clear sentence that occurs in the middle of any audiofile, but not exactly in the middle. So you tell me there is currently no tool that supports searching for an audio snippet and returning timestamps? because with that info I could just cut out those audio snippets.

I'm really suprised. We have all those magic apps, but no easy audio tools.

Comment: To not pollute the comments section I'm expanding my answer.

Comment: ... aaaand I forgot in my expansion that I'm talking about *uncompressed* data. MP3 is quite heavily compressed. How compression mangles the data depends on the *entirety* of said data. Which means that a compressed word "hello" in one audio file is a completely different string of bytes than in the next one...